# Compare Two Different Structured Arrays in Swift3

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am new to IOS as well as Swift Language, now I am working in Swift3.

DetailsArray:

```
[{
    bookId = abcd;
    bookName = "MyBook";
    bookThumbImage = ".jpg"
},
 {
    bookId = efgh;
    bookName = "MyBook1";
    bookThumbImage = "bookefgh.jpg"
},
{
    bookId = ijkl;
    bookName = "MyBook2";
    bookThumbImage = ".jpg"
}
]
```

When i print my Existing IdListArray Object is in the below given format,

IdListArray:

```
▿ Optional<"NSMutableArray">
    ▿ some : 2 elements
- 0 : abcd
- 1 : ijkl
```

Now i need to match these two Arrays (IdListArray & DetailsArray), to get the matched row record from my DetailsArray

Required Output:

```
[{
    bookId = abcd;
    bookName = "MyBook";
    bookThumbImage = ".jpg"
},
{
    bookId = ijkl;
    bookName = "MyBook2";
    bookThumbImage = ".jpg"
}]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please share some piece of code. How you are getting the values in this array's.?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is all stored arrays in some specified structure as given above.

Comment: Can i know the type of array they have declared.?

Comment: DetailsArray = [Any]()

Comment: what about  IdListArray.?

Comment: IdListArray = Its NSMutuableArray

Comment: I guess i am not clear with you content. can you edit your question and also post the updated print(IdListArray)

Comment: Details Array has more details of books stored in some specific structure [Any]() as given above. Next, the IdListArray has just the detail of the bookId in the array format NSMutuable Array. Now i need to check for the available book id from IdListArray and to get the details of the same from DetailsArray

Comment: Please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edited: As per your Requirement

You can use this code:

```
    var arrMatchingId:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var arrNotMatchingId:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for data in arrList{

        let id = (data as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "bookId")

        if arrID.contains(id!){
            arrMatchingId.add(data) //Id Matched
        }else{
            arrNotMatchingId.add(data)// Id Not Matched
        }
    }
    print(arrMatchingId) // This is the array with matched ID
    print(arrNotMatchingId) //This is the array with Unmatched array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine....at the same time, how i get the unmatched records at the same time , (i.e) {
    bookId = efgh;
    bookName = "MyBook1";
    bookThumbImage = "bookefgh.jpg"
}

Comment: I have worked and got the required result. It was very useful.

Comment: Do Approve the answer if it helped you, with the green tick

Comment: @MuraliDharanV Please see the edited answer for you reference, For getting matched and unmatched records.